# Cannot align images in array (atlas) - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, for-loop

I want simple animation from atlas textures in orders win1, win2, win3. My code:

```
var Image = SKSpriteNode()
var ImageAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var ImageArray = [SKTexture]()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    ImageAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Images")
    for i in 1...ImageAtlas.textureNames.count{
        let textureName = "win\(i).png"
        let texture = ImageAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
        ImageArray.append(texture)
    }

    let firstFrame = ImageArray[0]
    Image = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrame)
    Image.setScale(0.7)
    Image.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.width / -1.5)
    Image.zPosition = 2

    self.addChild(Image)
```

...

```
Image.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: ImageArray, timePerFrame : 0.01)))
```

...

When I play animation, textures are not in align win1, win2, win3 but for example win3, win1, win2. What is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: So is win3 appearing first?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally! Both codes working! Thanks! For me, It was not working, because in atlas was cached old informations. I must use Clean function. (Product -> Clean).

Answer (score 1):

`SKTextureAtlas`.`textureNames` makes no promises about the order of the array. If you want them in a certain order, you should sort them yourself.

There's also a few style issues in your code — note that variable names should be in lowerCamelCase, or other people (and tools like SO's syntax highlighter) will have a hard time telling them apart from types. Here's a refit to fix several things:

```
// don't allocate dummy values, just leave these nil until loaded
var imageNode: SKSpriteNode!
var atlas: SKTextureAtlas!
var textures: [SKTexture]!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Images")

    // sort array, convert from names to textures with map
    textures = atlas.textureNames.sorted().map { atlas.textureNamed($0) }

    guard let firstFrame = textures.first
        else { fatalError("missing textures") }

    imageNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrame)
    imageNode.setScale(0.7)
    imageNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.width / -1.5)
    imageNode.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(imageNode)   

}
```

...

```
// use implicit member lookup for terser syntax
imageNode.run(.repeatForever(.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 0.01)))
```

The only thing to watch out for here is that Swift Standard Library's `sorted()` is a naive sort for strings: if you have more than ten textures with names like `win1, win2, ..., win10, win11`, it'll sort them as `win1, win10, win11, win2, ...`. You can correct this by using some of the bridged sorting methods from `NSArray` that use locale-aware comparisons.

Comment: I´m desperate :( I have code exactly like you write, but stil not work. I /* comment */ all other code around your code. NSLog still shows : ["win6.png", "win1.png", "win9.png", "win4.png", "win7.png", "win2.png", "win5.png", "win8.png", "win3.png"] ... all code are in GameScene.swift ...

Answer (score 1):

The following usually works well for me when it comes to creating animations.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

   var TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
   var playerArray = [SKTexture]()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

                   //just replace "playerWon" with the name of your atlas folder
   TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "playerWon") 
   for i in 1...TextureAtlas.textureNames.count {
       let Name = "win\(i).png" //replace "win" with whatever name your .png files have
       playerArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
     }

   let playerNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: TextureAtlas.textureNames[0])


   }



 }
```